# Special alignment/input on pdf fields with itextsharp like for zip codes

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, acrofields

I've got some trouble when I fill a PDF-Form with itextsharp. There are special fields e. g. the zip code. The pdf formular that I have to use is an specification that can't be modified!

That's when I put numbers in with my own hands:
[normal user input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltq8m.jpg)

And that's happend when filled with itextsharp:
[itextsharp input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyPhe.jpg)

I don't know how to create this alignment. It appears automatically when the user type it in and leave the field with the mouse, or a tab.

So far I've tried this. It works all fine, but I can't activate this special
effect. It's just center the alignment. The pdfForm is an "AcroFields":

```
            foreach (var field in pdfForm.Fields) {
            wordVarsWithContent.Where(v => pdfForm.GetField(field.Key).Trim().ToLower().Contains(v.VarName.Trim().ToLower()))
                .ToList().ForEach(wordVarContent => {
                    if (wordVarContent != null) {
                        pdfForm.GetFieldItem(field.Key).GetMerged(0).Put(PdfName.Q, new PdfNumber(PdfFormField.Q_CENTER));
                        pdfForm.SetField(field.Key, pdfForm.GetField(field.Key).Replace(wordVarContent.VarName.Trim(), wordVarContent.Ergebnis));
                    }
                });

        }
```

Comment: That looks like a comb field and that's supported. Please post the PDF.

Comment: Original pdf file (plz save the file for edit): http://www.deutsche-rentenversicherung.de/Allgemein/de/Inhalt/5_Services/04_formulare_und_antraege/_pdf/G0810_01_01_08.pdf?__blob=publicationFile&v=10

Comment: The alignment is done with javascript, it won't work with iText.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Soares.